# How to run Azuredevops buildagent in azure container instance

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-container-instances, azure-devops-server-2019

I was following the [document][1] to run the azuredevops buildagents in containers. I have created the vsts docker image by following the MS docs. but after that microsoft document is not clear on some parts where i am stuck.

- Is Microsoft is providing any officila image for vsts,based on linux.
- is it possible to create redhat based vsts custom image than the default ubuntu image.

Also We need to run these containers in AzureContainer instance. But what are steps to achieve that?

If we run the vsts agents in AzureContaineInstances , will the on-demand autoscaling will work as per the number of pipeline executions are triggered at a time? how the scaling behaviour of AzureContaine instance?

Which is better option to select AzureContainer Instance or AKS ?

Comment: This is a very broad question. We can only help on specific issues you are facing - discussion-oriented questions are out of scope for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

> Is Microsoft is providing any officila image for vsts,based on linux.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux) a Dockerfile for running containerized Azure DevOps agent in the official documentation. The Dockerfile is based on Ubuntu 18.

> is it possible to create RedHat based vsts custom image then the
> default ubuntu image.

This can be possible by replacing the base image with Redhat and making necessary changes to the Dockerfile to avoid any errors.

I don't have much experience with ACI, but [this](https://medium.com/@cloudlabs01/running-azure-self-hosted-agent-in-azure-container-instance-aci-ad1fa338d769) should provide a reasonable set of guidelines for you to start running your ADO agents on ACI.

> Which is better option to select AzureContainer Instance or AKS ?

If all you want to run the containerized ADO agents for your pipelines, then ACI can be a better choice. However, if you already have an AKS cluster for your application, then its better to deploy your agents in a separate namespace within the same cluster. For auto-scaling of your agents based on the demand, a CRD can be used. Here are some useful blogs that you can find helpful.

https://moimhossain.com/2021/04/24/elastic-self-hosted-pool-for-azure-devops/

https://keda.sh/blog/2021-05-27-azure-pipelines-scaler/

Comment: This can be possible by replacing the base image with Redhat and making necessary changes to the Dockerfile to avoid any errors.   ---- I guess  Microsoft is not supporting to running the agents otherthan ubuntu for linux. Are u sure on this ?

Comment: @Vowneee as I mentioned, there's no official redhat based image. You would have to write one from scratch and install all base packages required to run `./start.sh` script